# Why I cannot use python module concurrent.futures in class method?

Tags: python, class, parallel-processing, class-method, concurrent.futures

I want to make my class method runs parallel, but it only produces some kind of error that I can not solve.
My code is:

```
import concurrent.futures as futures

samples = ['asfd', 'zxcv', 'asf', 'qwer']

class test:
    def __init__(self, samples):
        maturedb = {}
        with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as exe:
            for samplename, dResult in exe.map(self.make_readdb, samples):
                maturedb[samplename] = dResult
        print(maturedb)

    def make_readdb(self, samplename):
        return samplename, 1

test(samples)
```

If I run this code in Ubuntu machine, an Error like below occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 272, in _feedsend(obj)
    _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'method'>: attribute lookup builtins.method failed
```

The method `make_readdb` is just simplified to make an example, but it is an bottleneck in real code and
I need to make it parallel.

Comment: your code works on Python 3.3 as is

Comment: I tested my codes on Python 3.5.2, and it worked well. Many thanks to all your answers.

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html):

> The ProcessPoolExecutor class is an Executor subclass that uses a pool
> of processes to execute calls asynchronously. ProcessPoolExecutor uses
> the multiprocessing module, which allows it to side-step the Global
> Interpreter Lock but also means that **only picklable objects can be
> executed** and returned.

Try a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor)

I looked over your code again, the problem is that the function - `make_readdb` - is a member of the class `test`. Can you refactor and pull this function out?

Comment: Multithreading is not helping at all. Since cPython run only one thread at one time, ThreadPoolExecutor makes it even slower. In this case, single thread design took ~600 sec while ThreadPoolExecutor took ~1300 sec.

Comment: Is your job CPU bound or IO bound? What value did you use for max_workers? 

In your call to ProcessPoolExecutor, this will default to the number of processors in your machine.

Answer (score 1):

`self` should be passed as an explicit argument, even in multiple processes.
like this:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, samples):
        maturedb = {}
        with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as exe:
            for samplename, dResult in exe.map(test.make_readdb,self, samples):
                maturedb[samplename] = dResult
        print(maturedb)

    def make_readdb(self, samplename):
        return samplename, 1
```

But only one process will actually run.
So this might be a better way to write it:
[Do not pass self to ProcessPoolExecutor in the class](https://linuxtut.com/en/d41dcf11a5d16c33285f/)

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, samples):
        maturedb = {}
        with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as exe:
            for samplename, dResult in exe.map(test.make_readdb, samples):
                maturedb[samplename] = dResult
        print(maturedb)

    @staticmethod
    def make_readdb(samplename):
        return samplename, 1
```